# Find nested min/max array in a two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I easily get the array the contains the min and max values from a 2d array in JavaScript?

Below you can find the dateset. I only want to check the min and max values of the second element (eg 1.40, 1.38, 1.35).

```
[1622306648284, 1.4025036293793085],
[1622309604992, 1.384071162873584],
[1622312530257, 1.3503030062861177],
[1622315654724, 1.3625441847416848],
[1622318703104, 1.3645747739529213],
[1622321575558, 1.3611235799170127],
[1622324539379, 1.3750838657128996],
[1622327549644, 1.378768535066251],
[1622330652746, 1.3916061750979443],
[1622333538315, 1.4076792700030256],
[1622336466156, 1.3674852893896725]
```

So the expected output will be.

Min: [1622321575558, 1.3503030062861177]
Max: [1622333538315, 1.4076792700030256]

Thanks

Comment: Why the output has `1.36` when there is a `1.35`?

Comment: what you tried to solve your problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output you wanted is strange, but this does the trick.

```js
const arr = [[1622306648284, 1.4025036293793085],[1622309604992, 1.384071162873584],[1622312530257, 1.3503030062861177],[1622315654724, 1.3625441847416848],[1622318703104, 1.3645747739529213],[1622321575558, 1.3611235799170127],[1622324539379, 1.3750838657128996],[1622327549644, 1.378768535066251],[1622330652746, 1.3916061750979443],[1622333538315, 1.4076792700030256],[1622336466156, 1.3674852893896725]];

const max = arr.reduce((a, b) => a[1] >= b[1] ? a : b);
const min = arr.reduce((a, b) => a[1] <= b[1] ? a : b);

console.log(`Min: ${min} Max: ${max}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the array by using an object with min and max values.

```js
const
    data = [[1622306648284, 1.4025036293793085], [1622309604992, 1.384071162873584], [1622312530257, 1.3503030062861177], [1622315654724, 1.3625441847416848], [1622318703104, 1.3645747739529213], [1622321575558, 1.3611235799170127], [1622324539379, 1.3750838657128996], [1622327549644, 1.378768535066251], [1622330652746, 1.3916061750979443], [1622333538315, 1.4076792700030256], [1622336466156, 1.3674852893896725]],
    result = data.reduce(({ min, max }, a) => {
        if (a[1] < min[1]) min = a;
        if (a[1] > max[1]) max = a;
        return { min, max };
    }, { min: [, Number.MAX_VALUE], max: [, -Number.MAX_VALUE] });

console.log(result);
```